# Find first value by group and create column with that value for all rows in the group once value is found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom'],
    'Sequence': [2021, 2022, 2023, 2024],
    'Car': ['Ford', 'Chevy', 'Tesla', NaN]}
```

I want to create a new column called "new_car" that finds the first value of "Chevy", and copies it down the rest of the group.

So if I group by "Name", find first instance of Car = 'Chevy', and rest of column is listed as 'Chevy'.

Here's how the new column would appear:
'new_car': [NaN, 'Chevy', 'Chevy' , 'Chevy']

Not sure how to accomplish this in pandas...any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask the non-Chevy values with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html), then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['new_car'] = df['Car'].where(df['Car'].eq('Chevy')).ffill()
```

Alternatively, you can also [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) per group:

```
df['new_car'] = (df['Car'].where(df['Car'].eq('Chevy'))
                 .groupby(df['Name']).ffill()
                )
```

Output:

```
  Name  Sequence    Car new_car
0  Tom      2021   Ford     NaN
1  Tom      2022  Chevy   Chevy
2  Tom      2023  Tesla   Chevy
3  Tom      2024    NaN   Chevy
```